# Print "welcome" in different languages in JS

Tags: javascript

The task is to print a hello message depending on the chosen language. I am given an object literal. For example, if user chooses 'dutch', the program will print 'Welkom' and so on. If the language is not found, the program should print the default language, which is English. I have been able to do most of the problem, except one thing, now in the present code when a language is found, it also prints a welcome message in English, what am I missing?

```js
var o = {
  english: 'Welcome',
  czech: 'Vitejte',
  danish: 'Velkomst',
  dutch: 'Welkom',
  estonian: 'Tere tulemast',
  finnish: 'Tervetuloa',
  flemish: 'Welgekomen',
  french: 'Bienvenue',
  german: 'Willkommen',
  irish: 'Failte',
  italian: 'Benvenuto',
  latvian: 'Gaidits',
  lithuanian: 'Laukiamas',
  polish: 'Witamy',
  spanish: 'Bienvenido',
  swedish: 'Valkommen',
  welsh: 'Croeso'
}

function GetLang(arg) {

  for (key in o) {
    if (arg === key) {
      console.log(o[key])
    }
  }
  if (arg !== key) {
    console.log(o.english)
  }

}
GetLang('danish');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use directly the parameter `arg` and use it as a check if this property in the array. You get then the value, otherwise you get the value of the `english` property.

```
return o[arg] || o.english;
```

```js
var o = {
         english: 'Welcome',
         czech: 'Vitejte',
         danish: 'Velkomst',
         dutch: 'Welkom',
         estonian: 'Tere tulemast',
         finnish: 'Tervetuloa',
         flemish: 'Welgekomen',
         french: 'Bienvenue',
         german: 'Willkommen',
         irish: 'Failte',
         italian: 'Benvenuto',
         latvian: 'Gaidits',
         lithuanian: 'Laukiamas',
         polish: 'Witamy',
         spanish: 'Bienvenido',
         swedish: 'Valkommen',
         welsh: 'Croeso'
    };

function GetLang(arg) {
    return o[arg] || o.english;
}

console.log(GetLang('danish'));
```

Comment: It's better not to console.log from the function and just return message.

Comment: That is so simple and requires so little code. Thank you a lot! For some reason, I did not think of such simple solutions

Comment: there is no need to iterate an object if you know the key. you can directly address it.

Comment: dfsq, would please explain why it is better to not console.log from a function? I am a newbie, this info will be useful for me

Answer (score 1):

BTW the reason why your code was printing both the desired language **and** english (or english twice) in your original code is that the execution of the function continues even after you have found your result - the browser has no clue you are happy with that result and you must thus tell it to stop there. Even the snippet of Nina is a much more elegant solution to the problem, here is your code where I've added a return statement, which should work as well:

```js
function GetLang(arg) {

  for (key in o) {
    if (arg === key) {
      console.log(o[key])
      return // we have found the result, do not continue execution of the function
    }
  }
  
  if (arg !== key) {
    console.log(o.english) // the function ends here, there is no need for an explicit return statement here
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, now I understand! Your explanation shows where I was wrong, thank you)

Comment: And placing the logging function outside of the `GetLang` makes the function more reusable - imagine you need to place the welcome message in a heading of the page. You can't use the original code, because it places the text in the console and most of the users won't ever notice it on your website. You would have to write a different function `GetLangAsHeading` which would be nearly identical, but would place the text in the heading.